# Prevent sharing of ASP.NET authentication cookie across domains

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two ASP.NET MVC applications on different sub domains. I noticed that authentication cookie is being shared between both applications. Hence, a logged on user on application A will be authenticated in application B or vice versa.

How do I prevent this? Most questions i have seen here only discussed about how to actually share authentication cookies which is opposite of my case.

I have tried to set the domain property in cookie options in Owin startup class but no luck

Comment: You can set the authentication cookie for the specific domain and for the wild card domain name.

Comment: Thanks @ChetanRanpariya. I noticed that when i set the domain property in cookie options. authentication did not work.